# Assign value to element of dynamic array

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic

I have two arrays:

`char line[128]` which is populated using:

```
fgets(line,sizeof line, file)
```

and

```
char* array;
  array=(char*) malloc(j*sizeof(char));
```

where j is some integer.

I'd like to assign an element of "line" to the corresponding element of "array".

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: `line[i] = array[i]`?  Or do I have it backwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As these are char arrays you could just use strcpy

```
 strcpy(array,line);
```

taking care that your dynamic array is large enough to accomodate the line array. This would copy the whole array, or for just an individual element,

```
 array[i] = line[i];
```

taking care that i is within limits of the arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
 array[N] = line[N]; // N is the corresponding element's index
```

But you have to make sure that `N` is a valid index w.r.t both `array` and `line`.